# Loop through array to find if the array contains certain names with if statement

Tags: javascript

I don't use JavaScript much and I know this shouldn't be this difficult. Basically, is what I am trying to do is loop through an array of domain names that I am getting from the users input. ex. `[gmail.com, yahoo.com, xyz.com, etc..]`. I am using a for loop and if statements to run through it just to check if the array has a certain type of email. So if I am searching for yahoo.com I need to know if there is a gmail.com in there as well.

**Here is what I have created so far but I cannot get it to check the second or third or fourth email.**

```js
function EmailFunction() {
  var emailNames = [fdsg@gmail.com, gjitrerh@yahoo.com, jirg@aol.com];
  var emailDomains = [];
  var arrEmail = emailNames.split(', ');
  
  var len = arrEmail.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var domain = arrEmail[i].split("@").pop();
    emailDomains.push(domain)
    var unique = emailDomains.filter(onlyUnique);
    for (var j = 0; j < unique.length; j++) {
      if (unique[j] == "yahoo.com") {
        var answer = confirm("* Please verify your Email addresses are being sent to the correct personnel.\n\n *** Please press CANCEL to Verify.\n *** Press OK to continue.");
        if (answer == true) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }

      } else {
        var answer = confirm("* Since you have emails that are not yahoo.COM please retype your emails.\n\n *** Please press CANCEL to Verify.\n *** Press OK to continue.");

        if (answer == true) {
          return true;
        } else {
          $('.txbx1').show();
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }

> **Edit:**I edited my question with some temp data.
> I am getting the full email from the user ex. xyz@yahoo.com. 
I am then splitting that at the @ sign so that I get an 
array of emails like = yahoo.com, aol.com, gmail.com.
> I am then need to loop through that 
array `unique` to check if the array has a 
certain email domain.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML as well and indicate the precise output you need.

Comment: you return directly in the first loop.

Comment: I've added a [Stack Snippet] to your question. If you [edit] your question, you can edit the snippet and add enough HTML to create a [mre]

Comment: To elaborate on @NinaScholz's comment, which is the cause for not looping over all domains: when you use a return statement in JavaScript the function currently being executed will be left, so the for loop never goes beyond the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Make a set object and define all the domains you wish in it. Then just use has() method in your if statement like that:

```
if (mySet.has(unique[j])) {
```

[Syntax here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has)